# ASP.NET MVC4 repository injection to controller that depends on currently logged user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, code-injection, authorize

Let's say I am creating a "TODO list" web application with following features:

- have ability to register/login users
- each user has it's own TODO list that is independent from other users

So I've created a simple model that has class ToDoItem.

I'd like to use good practices so I created a generic repository that should fetch TODO items from database:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    void Add(T newEntity);
    void Remove(T entity);

    T FindById(long id);
}
```

(implementation is done with EF and code-first approach but that's not important right now)

This repository will be injected into controller that allows user to list, add, remove, edit TODO items. This is done via custom controller factory I've created that uses Ninject DI container to resolve repository interface to concrete implementation.
So the controller looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IRepository<ToDoItem> _repository;
    public HomeController(IRepository<ToDoItem> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // list all TODO items for this user
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ListItems()
    {
        var todoItems = _repository.FindAll();
        return View(todoItems);
    }

}
```

My question what is the best way to make controller return TODO list only for the currently logged in user? Ideally I'd like to have controller work with repository that is injected and pre-set with the currently logged user. In other words I'd like to avoid this kind of code in action method:

```
    // list all TODO items for this user
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ListItems()
    {
        var todoItems = _repository.FindAll(User.Identity);
        return View(todoItems);
    }
```

I was thinking that possible solution would be to make controller factory somehow know which user is logged so it would initialize concrete repository and set user ID so that controller doesn't have to do that in every action method. Would this be good approach and if so how can I implement it? If not, what are better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle this in one of two ways:

1.
Make the lifestyle of the repository be per web request and take a dependency on the `User.Identity` such that this can be used inside of the repository methods. e.g.

```
public class Repository<ToDoItem> : IRepository<ToDoItem>
{
    private IIdentity _identity;

    // let the container inject the IIdentity into the repository
    // (you will need to register a service with 
    //  the container for IIdentity for this)
    public Repository(IIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    IQueryable<ToDoItem> FindAll()
    {
        return FromSomeContext().Where(x => x.Username == _identity.Name);
    }

    // ....
}
```

Then register a method with Ninject that it can call to resolve an `IIdentity` for any component that requires it. (You may decide that injecting an `IPrincipal` is more useful as you can get information about user roles with it too).

```
kernel.Bind<IIdentity>()
      .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity)
      .InRequestScope();
```

Now, assuming that Ninject is also constructing your controllers for you and you have registered components for the `IRepository<T>` services that your application requires, The current user `IIdentity` will be injected into the `Repository<ToDoItem>` for you by Ninject.

2.
Create an extension method for `IRepository<ToDoItem>` (or even `IRepository<T>` if appropriate) that wraps adding the `Where()` expression for limiting the returned TODO items only to those that are relevant to the current user.

Comment: Since repository is injected into controller that makes its lifecycle tied to web request right? However, I want to avoid controller's code to depend on currently logged user and use repository that will already return data for the current user. For example, imagine I've first created this application without multi-user support. Now how would I extend it for multi-user support the easiest way? Eg. controllers should be left intact and only change repositories to return data for currently logged user. Hope this clears up my problem a bit more...

Comment: the lifestyle of the repository is not tied to the web request; it could for example have a singleton lifestyle meaning that the same instance of the repository is injected into every newly created controller instance. I understand a bit more now about what you want to do, but I'm not sure that wishing to avoid modifying controller code is the best way to achieve it. Having said that, `HttpContext.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` should both be set to the `IPrincipal` representing the current user so you could use these inside your repository methods...

Comment: Injecting the `IPrincipal` or `IIdentity` would probably make the repository more testable, but it does mean the lifestyle of the repository would need to be per web request (or shorter).

Comment: Thanks for the code example, it clears up a lot confusion. One additional question I have is how/where should I instantiate this Repository<ToDoItem>? I suppose this should be done in my custom controller factory but in that case where do I get this IIdentity to inject in Repository<ToDoItem>? A short code sample of that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The `Repository<ToDoItem>` is going to be instantiated by Ninject for you, as are your controllers, if you are utilizing IoC and Dependency Injection. I've added additional detail to the question, but it sounds like you might want to take a look at how to use Ninject with an MVC application - https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Answer (score 0):

For those, who use Windsor Castle:

```
container.Register(
...
Component.For<IIdentity>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity; })
    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
...);
```

**Note:**

```
Component.For<ICustomer>().Instance(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity)
```

does not work, because "When you register an existing instance, even if you specify a lifestyle it will be ignored.", see [Windsor Castle Documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Register_existing_instance%3a_5)